# Legend as Table under a Table

Tags: tables

There are two tables, where the second one is the legend of the first one. How can I combine these easily without destroying the first or second table's layout?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tabular}{|lccccc|}
    \small{333333333333333333} & E1111MP & EMP       & EMP  & adddW        & SOW          \\ 
    \small{4444444444444444}   & CsssON  & 222d2EMP  & D    & HAAAddddddW  & Erad23P      \\ 
    \small{555555}             & EEEP    & BRxxxxxRR & TTMP & TTxxxxxxxxMP & EMXxx xxxxXP \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tabular}{|lcc|} 
    \small{444444 4444444444} & Csddddddddss ddd dddddddd & dasadafasdfa               \\ 
    \small{555555}            & EEEP                      & BRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRR \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: maybe this one is easier to understand:

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|lccccc|}
\small{333333333333333333}  & E1111MP & EMP & EMP & adddW & SOW \\small{4444444444444444}    & CsssON & 222d2EMP & D & HAAAddddddW & Erad23P  \\small{555555}              & EEEP & BRxxxxxRR & TTMP & TTxxxxxxxxMP & EMXxx xxxxXP \\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|lcc|}
\small{444444 4444444444}    & Csddddddddss ddd dddddddd & dasadafasdfa    \\small{555555}              & EEEP & BRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRR \\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Comment: sorry for the formatting ;)

Answer (score 8):

Put *both* in *one* `table` environment.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tabular}{|lccccc|}
    \small{333333333333333333} & E1111MP & EMP       & EMP  & adddW        & SOW          \\ 
    \small{4444444444444444}   & CsssON  & 222d2EMP  & D    & HAAAddddddW  & Erad23P      \\ 
    \small{555555}             & EEEP    & BRxxxxxRR & TTMP & TTxxxxxxxxMP & EMXxx xxxxXP \\ 
  \end{tabular}

  \begin{tabular}{|lcc|} 
    \small{444444 4444444444} & Csddddddddss ddd dddddddd & dasadafasdfa               \\ 
    \small{555555}            & EEEP                      & BRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRR \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most underestimated trick regarding tabulars.

Comment: Herbert you are right!

never thought on that easy way! TNX A LOT!

Comment: this is very useful.